# Why Phonegap deviceready event is fired after a very long time?

Tags: ios, cordova

I used phonegap cloud build service to build the iOS app. But the deviceready event fires after a very long time, about more than 20 seconds.

In my case, I ran my app in iphone-4s. Does any knows any possible reasons?

I think Phonegap shouldn't be so slow on iOS. I wonder if it's because of my iOS certificate? need distribution profiling? Any other configs?

It seems the phonegap native code runs for a long time, and then the device ready is fired.

Thanks for any ideas. Thank you!

Comment: i was using phonegap 2.3

Comment: How did you find out that it took 20 seconds?

Comment: I alert(some thing) in the device ready event handler. Since I start the app, it's 20 seconds long when the alert shows.

Comment: Please post the code in your index.html along with the deviceready event call

Comment: I have found out the reason. When I open my wifi, the startup becomes very slow, when the wifi is closed, the startup is very quick. Any one knows how to disable connecting to network when the app starts?

Comment: Your app cannot disconnect the WiFi connectivity. iOS wont allow it. This is something specific to your app. You need to post some code for us to figure out  whats the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I know the reason. It's because phonegap native code automatically connect to it's website when the app starts, and I'm in china, the network to phonegap website is very slow, so it takes about 30 seconds. After the 30 seconds, the deviceready event is fired, and splashscreen disappear. Do you know how to config the app  to not visit phonegap website?

Answer (score 0):

Are you not including cordova.js in the local file system? if its in the local file system, there is no reason why it should connect to PhoneGap website. Also move all your JS,CSS files to the local file system and do not use an CDNs. Then your app will be much faster.

Comment: thanks. i have included the cordova.js. In my case, when I close the wifi, my app works very well, and the startup is very quick.

Comment: Now that you are here, please mark the post which was most useful to as the 'answer' to the question so that its helpful for others.

Comment: there IS only one post