# phonegap - how to disable connecting to network when the app starts?

Tags: cordova

I have found the reason why the splashscreen shows too long.

When I open my wifi, the startup becomes very slow, when the wifi is closed, the startup is very quick. I then know phonegap automatically connects to network when app starts, probably connects to phonegap website.

As I'm in china, the network to phonegap website is very slow, so it takes about 30 seconds.

Any one knows how to disable connecting to network when the app starts?

Many thanks!

Leo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Phonegap deviceready event is fired after a very long time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528421/why-phonegap-deviceready-event-is-fired-after-a-very-long-time)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Phonegap Build, you'll need to edit the config.xml file, there's documentation about that [here](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml)

If you're building through an IDE, then you'll have to edit the manifest.xml file - there's a tutorial for Android apps [here](http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2012/11/11/cordova-2-2-android-app-creation-in-mountain-lion-with-eclipse-from-install-to-google-play/) - about halfway down there's some reference to manifest.xml, it's under option '4' of 'Update Eclipse Files'

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using phonegap build. But I have include the config.xml, but I didn't see any configuration that disables connecting to phonegap website. Do you know which configuration?